# Как прокрутить блок влево до нужного места?

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка

Добрый день! Появилась такая задача, которую даже понятия не имею, как возможно решить. Смысл в следующем: при нажатии на блок красного цвета, блок `.blk` должен прокрутиться влево до левого края экрана. Прошу прощения за тавтологию. И благодарю за помощь!

```css
.wrp {
display: block;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
visibility: visible;
overflow-x: scroll;
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
background: #cccccc;
}
.blk {
display: block;
position: relative;
width: 1000px;
height: 500px;
z-index: 2;
margin-left: 100%;
background: #aabbcc;
}
.knop {
display: block;
position: absolute;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
right: 10px;
top: 50%;
background: red;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrp">
<div class="knop"></div>
<div class="blk"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(".knop").click(function() {
  $(".wrp").animate({
     scrollLeft:$(".knop").offset().left+20
  }, 1000)

})
```

```css
.wrp {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: visible;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #cccccc;
}
.blk {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-left: 100%;
  background: #aabbcc;
}
.knop {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrp">
  <div class="knop"></div>
  <div class="blk"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(".knop").click(function(){
$(".blk").animate({
  'margin-left': "10%"
},1000)
$(".knop").animate({
  'left': "6%"
},1000)
})
```

```css
.wrp {
display: block;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
visibility: visible;
overflow-x: scroll;
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
background: #cccccc;
}
.blk {
display: block;
position: relative;
width: 1000px;
height: 500px;
z-index: 2;
margin-left: 100%;
background: #aabbcc;
}
.knop {
display: block;
position: absolute;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
right: 10px;
top: 50%;
background: red;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrp">
<div class="knop"></div>
<div class="blk"></div>
</div>
```